# HTTP Request Code 206 Spotify Server Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, spotify, spotify-app

I am trying to get the user authorization code for the authentication flow. When sending the get request with Python and requests I have two dictionaries for headers and params, yet I get the 206 response and server error. I have all the mandatory parameters and header fields. Ignore any indent problems, they're just pasted wrong. There should be no problems related to my spotify dev account affecting the app/client.

```
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    code_params = {
        'response_type': 'code',
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
        'scope': 'user-read-private user-read-email',
    }


    code = requests.get('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize', params=code_params, headers=headers).json()
```

Comment: 206 is not an error, _per se_ but a return code to indicate that partial content may be sent from the server when the client has asked for a range.  This is used for downloading data in parts (especially for large content)

Comment: The response code is 206, but the json response is {'error': 'server_error'}

Comment: That request is getting a website; not a json object. The [Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/) is more complex than your code. Also, the header should be `headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}`. Because it returns html code, and not json, json() causes an error. See: print(code.text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the authentication code request is supposed to redirect you to login and give permissions. Instead of calling .json() , you need to use .url and navigate to that website to get that redirect.